# Ambiguous call between within Mono for System.Linq.Enumerable.Max

Tags: c#, linq, mono

When using a lambda expression to find the maximum Key value from the following code I get the following compile error when compiling on a Unix system using gmcs:

```
List<KeyValuePair<int, RunnerBase>> lsFinishOrder = new List<KeyValuePair<int, RunnerBase>>();

...fill out List...

iMaxPlace = lsFinishOrder.Max(p => p.Key);
```

The code compiles fine on a Windows machine and performs as expected when executed the issue only arises when I try to compile it on Linux.

> error CS0121: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or
>   properties:
>   `System.Linq.Enumerable.Max<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>>,
>   System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>, **long** >)'
>
> and
>   `System.Linq.Enumerable.Max<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>>,
>   System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int,Pathfinder.RunnerBase>, **int** >)'
>
> /usr/lib/mono/gac/System.Core/3.5.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Core.dll
>   (Location of the symbol related to previous error)

Any ideas would be welcome as I've tried a lot of different approaches and I'm wondering if I'm not looking in the wrong places. I'm targeting .Net 3.5 on my windows build.

Comment: I cleaned up the error message to make it a bit more readable and I've inserted the ** around the **long** and **int** that seems to be causing the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in Mono's compiler.

Try this to help it:

```
iMaxPlace = lsFinishOrder.Max((Func<KeyValuePair<int, RunnerBase>, int>)(p => p.Key));
```

Comment: Fantastic I've tried that and Mono is completely happy with it!

Comment: Thanks very much for your help! (Sorry I posted 2 comments when you hit enter it posts instead of moving to the next line).